# From graphql types to javascript

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

In the graphql [documentation](http://graphql.org/docs/typesystem/) I see that they define the objects using simple annotations.
e.g.

```
type Droid : Character {
  id: String!
  name: String
  friends: [Character]
  appearsIn: [Episode]
  primaryFunction: String
}
```

They also describe rules such as using ! for mandatory in this simple form.

But in the project the simple form is in comment and the java script that describes it looks differently.

Is there an automatic process that migrates the data from the simple form to the javascript?

Answer (score 1):

The simple annotations you referred to above are written in **GraphQL schema language**. GraphQL-js contains a parser for the schema language, and a bunch of utility functions to create a GraphQL-js Schema object from it. That schema can be used to validate queries, but it doesn't contain resolvers and resolveType functions so it is not executable without further modification.

There are however a couple of libraries, like [graphql-tools](https://github.com/apollostack/graphql-tools) (which I helped write), which make it easy to add resolvers and resolveType to a schema generated from GraphQL Schema language to make it executable.

Comment: Thanks. Trying to figure out how it works. Does it go over my commneted code and replaces it with java script? Because I can clearly see in the documentation rules to how to write this schema language.

Comment: It doesn't output code, it creates a javascript object. So you call the function from your program, give it a schema language string, and you get back the schema language object.